# Auth0 callback not working after deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, auth0

I build a webapp that uses auth0. Locally everything is just working fine, but after I deployed the app to Heroku the auth0 callback is just not working and gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**So here is my setup:**

- Auth0 Services is subscribed in Heroku
- Callback-Url in Auth0 is set to http://localhost:3000/callback
- /callback route is implemented (just a simple 200 response if it works)

**My guess where it fails:**

In the Auth0 logs I shows a successfull login and the browser redirects to http://localhost:3000/callback instead of the Heroku-URL. So it seemes to me that there is some kind of redirection missing.

Any help on this topic would be nice, since all the blogs and help-pages didn't help so far.

Comment: The callback URL in your app should be `https://your-app.herokuapp.com/callback`

Comment: @MattRaible when I set it this way I get a Callback URL mismatch, also having both in the list didn't help

Comment: @MattRaible ok never mind :D  --> I forgot to change my BASE_URL to the heroku url. After doing this in combination with the heroku url as callback it finally worked. Thank you!

Comment: @cinemandre Consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).